# Where used list in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a view, Wanted to check what sort of SQL can help to identify list of all views and Stored procedure using it.

**For Example,**
View A is being used in View B, View C and Stored Procedure D.
Is there any metadata schema which can help writing such query where we can track all dependent objects of a certain object in BigQuery. Please assist.

**For Example,**
View A is being used in View B, View C and Stored Procedure D.
Is there any metadata schema which can help writing such query where we can track all dependent objects of a certain object in BigQuery. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following query that will list all views, this can be done on an individual dataset basis. Of course if you have a set of datasets you could create one UNION ALL query for each dataset to combine the results.

```
SELECT * FROM dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(view_definition, 'dataset_name.table_name')
```

Replacing `dataset_name` and `table_name` in the above query.

`view_definition` in the schema table contains the actual SQL code to create the view. So we are essentially just searching that field for the table name, same would work if you are looking for a view being used in a view.